# Does Breeze js care what version of Json OData you are using?

Tags: json, breeze

I was wondering if Breeze js requires the use of Json verbose (Version 2.0) or light(Version 3.0), or if it can except both of these Odata versions of Json. Is one safer to use that the other? Also, is it posible to consume Atom OData (Just curious, not using it in my application)? Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing light is really all Breeze would need since it really only cares about the metadata from what I've seen. Just want to be sure before I fully commit though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breeze currently uses the [datajs](http://datajs.codeplex.com/documentation) library to provide support for any OData services.  So we are constrained by whatever formats this library understands. (and I'm not sure how this library handles Atom OData either)

Note that this is only true for OData services, for any Web Api controller provided services  JSON.NET provides a serialization format that is very comparable to the OData light format.

We have looked at providing a processing option that bypasses the datajs library and processes  OData payloads directly but we aren't there yet.